# Convergence in infinite double sequence

Tags: analysis, double-sequence

I was told in math class that with
$\sum\limits_{n=1}\limits^{\infty}\lvert{a_{mn}}\rvert = b_m$ and $\sum\limits_{m=1}\limits^{\infty}b_m<\infty$, we can conclude that $\sum\limits_{m=1}\limits^{\infty}a_{mn}<\infty$. I don't really see the connections, and am struggling to find out why this is the case. Why does this work?

Comment: Technically, since some $a_{mn}$ could be negative, your conclusion should not be "$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}<\infty$".  It should be "$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}$ converges".

Comment: Hint: $|a_{mn}|< b_m$.

Comment: @zkutch you mean $\leq$.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above by zkutch helped a lot. Since $\lvert a_{mn}\rvert \leq b_m$ and $\sum\limits_{m=1}\limits^{\infty}b_m<\infty$, $\sum\limits_{m=1}\limits^{\infty}\lvert a_{mn} \rvert < \infty$ and thus $\sum\limits_{m=1}\limits^{\infty}a_{mn}$ converges.